# What is the correct syntax for two related [DataContract] model classes represented in WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, model

I am new to WCF; this is my first try.

I created two projects using the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web. One is "WCF Service Application" and the other is a MVC Web application; the Web application consumes the WCF service.

I know the basics of making the communication possible between the Web application and the WCF service.

I will jump directly to to problem;
If I've two model classes represent two entities from the Database:

Stock:

```
public partial class Stock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Stocks = new HashSet<Stock>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map them to the WCF service **correctly** as [DataContract] classes; How?

This is my try:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    // List all Stocks
    [OperationContract]
    List<Stock> GetStocks();
}

[DataContract]
public class WCF_Stock
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual WCF_User User { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class WCF_User
{
    // Does this constructor require any special attributes?
    public WCF_User()
    {
        this.WCF_Stocks_Collection = new HashSet<WCF_Stock>();
    }

    [DataMember]        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<WCF_Stock> WCF_Stocks_Collection { get; set; }
}
```

**Please Note** the comment question above: Does this constructor require any special attributes?

Implementation for `IService1`:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private StockPEntities dbStock = new StockPEntities();

    public List<Stock> GetStocks()
    {
        return dbStock.Stocks.ToList<Stock>();
    }
 }
```

I consume it in the Web application:

```
public class WCFConsumerController : Controller
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client wcfService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(wcfService.GetStocks());
        }
    }
```

It gives `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

---

**But**; before adding the User entity to the database, and of course before adding the `WCF_User` `[DataContract]` to the WCF Service; that is when there was only the `WCF_Stock` alone, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class WCF_Stock
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The code at the Web application that consumes the WCF service works correctly; that is, this line returns a View with Data:

`return View(wcfService.GetStocks());`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create separate WCF_Stock class, and you don't have to mark classes using attributes. 
I think that you have problem with lazy loading mechanism in Entity Framework. Try to disable it in GetStocks method using following code:

dbStock.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnable = false;